# How to parameterize a regular expression in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have a variable

```
announcementName= test
```

I am trying to use **regEx Extractor** to match an expression in jmeter.

I am able to match data with the below expression.

```
{"id":(.*?),"announcementName":"test",
```

However I am unable to pass test as a variable to the same expression

```
 {"id":(.*?),"announcementName":"${announcementName}",
```

I am unable to match anything with the above regEx matching.

Can someone please let me know on how to pass parameters to **RegEx Extractor** in Jmeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my experience, if you try this approach in listener to verify whether correlation is working or not than obviously it's not going to work.

But if you are passing this directly in reg ex extractor and trigger the script then it should work provided the variable does not contain any special character like (.,?) etc. (As you mentioned test as value so seems you took an example to display here but actual value is something else, so please check actual value once again to confirm it's a simple string without any special characters)

Comment: my variable is a combination of random alphabets and numeric values. 
 announcementName= ${__RandomString(15,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789,)}

Comment: My Bad, Sorry about that.
I just noticed there was a space in my variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can check with __V() function.
i.e.
```

> {"id":(.*?),"announcementName":"${__V(${announcementName})}",